# Floating Point XOR

Tags: code-golf, bitwise, floating-point

Your task is pretty simple. Given two floats, bitwise xor the binary representation of them, and output that as a float.

For example,

```
Normal: 16.7472 ^ 123.61 = 7.13402e-37
Binary: 01000001100001011111101001000100 ^ 01000010111101110011100001010010 = 00000011011100101100001000010110

Normal: 2.2 ^ 4.4 = 1.17549e-38
Binary: 01000000000011001100110011001101 ^ 01000000100011001100110011001101 = 00000000100000000000000000000000

Normal: 7.898 ^ 3.4444 = 1.47705e-38
Binary: 01000000111111001011110001101010 ^ 01000000010111000110101001111111 = 00000000101000001101011000010101
```

Restrictions/clarifications:

- Input/output can be given by any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- The program can be a full program or just a function; either is fine.
- The float type can be any size, but the minimum size is 2 bytes.
- [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- Shortest code wins.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Could you provide some more test cases?

Comment: Does Boolean list count as a convenient method?

Comment: Why the lenient input format but stringent output format? How about Boolean list as output?

Comment: I would say no. I'll edit the question to clarify on what a "convenient method" is.

Comment: What if the resulting bit pattern doesn't represent a valid float?

Comment: I don't think that's possible...? I just wrote a program to bruteforce 4-byte floats from 0 to UINT_MAX, and it didn't die anywhere. NaN is a valid output, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @virchau With the exactly right input, it should be possible to produce the representation of a sNaN, causing an error.

Comment: I found the inputs that work with 8-byte floats (doubles) to produce an sNaN:
1.54234e+260 1.63233e-260
It doesn't throw an FPE on my system, though. Can you try it and see?

Comment: That gives me 1.675075421658194e-309.

Comment: "binary representation" of a float is extremely ambiguous. You'll need to define which representation you're using. There are an infinite number of representations, including the finite number already used by life on this planet, some being more popular than others, such as IEEE 754

Comment: Do we have to handle NaN input?

Comment: This question would be more interesting as "xor the *values*" rather than "xor the representations". The latter is of course identical to "xor two 32-bit integers" in any language that lacks a type system or admits type punning, and thus is pretty boring...

Comment: Do we have to handle infinity, subnormals, or negative 0, as either input or output?

Comment: @R.., you're assuming 32-bit IEEE-734.  XORing a pair of Microsoft Basic 40-bit floats is a bit more exciting.

Comment: @R..: Indeed -- and then of course input and output should be given as exact fractions. (It may be assumed that the input fractions are in lowest terms and the denominators are not powers of two, so the binary representations are unique).

Comment: @Mark: No, as written the question is just about xor'ing their representations, whatever those representations are. The result is dependent on the floating point format but the algorithm is always a single xor instruction on the representation, which is pretty boring.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Huh? These are floating point (diadic rationals) not arbitrary rationals. I don't even know what xor would mean on the latter.

Comment: @R..: Take their representations as (infinite, repeating) binary fractions, XOR them bit by bit; find out what the result represents?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: That's not mathematically meaningful, unlike xor of float values which is addition of polynomials over Z/2Z.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer: For languages that support floating point, I think it's implied that you should use the language's native object-representation, whatever that is.  (e.g. something equivalent to type-punning to integer and back).  If the language doesn't support type-punning or XOR of FP data, then you have to implement it yourself using whatever FP representation your chosen implementation uses.

Answer (score 57):

## x86-64 machine code, 4 bytes

```
0f 57 c1 c3
```

In assembly:

```
xorps xmm0, xmm1
ret
```

This is a callable function that takes two floats or doubles as arguments (in `xmm0` and `xmm1`) and returns a float or double (in `xmm0`).

That matches the calling conventions of both Windows x64 *and* the x86-64 SysV ABI, and works for floats as well as doubles.  (They're passed / returned in the low 4 or 8 bytes of XMM registers).

Answer (score 12):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>74</s> 32 bytes

```cpp
#define f(x,y)*(int*)x^=*(int*)y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcndCoMgGIDhc6/igyA0XGAbBaW7lIH4M4TSWAZKdO1uwY7eB161rre3UqVyXs27NsBd2OLHyOVZKm2s8wYsTjSTBjsfG5Je4q9cfoFFOo8JOhCAnYOMkATr2@ExdBSyYN297dl0TVwnWmdyeYt6HFXYI3AOaUJn@QI)

I haven’t previously golfed in C++ so am grateful to all those who helped halve the size of the code! A macro which takes pointers to two floats as its arguments and modified the first to return the result.

Thanks to @12Me1 for saving 2 bytes and @Arnauld for saving 4! Thanks to @Nishioka for saving another 14, @Neil a further 6 and @AZTECCO and @Nishioka another 11! Thanks to @PeterCordes for saving 5 bytes!

Comment: You can remove the linebreaks to save 2 chars, and this also works in C

Comment: You can save 4 more bytes with `z=*(int*)x^*(int*)y;`.

Comment: -2 bytes: `using F=float;F f(F*x,F*y){int z=*(int*)x^*(int*)y;return*(F*)&z;}`

Comment: Function-like macro, 63 bytes: `#define f(x,y)[&]{int z=*(int*)x^*(int*)y;return*(float*)&z;}()`

Comment: With gcc extensions, 54 bytes: `#define f(x,y)({int z=*(int*)x^*(int*)y;*(float*)&z;})`

Comment: Since you're using pointers, is it legal to use one of the inputs as the output? If so, you could write `(*(int*)x^=*(int*)y)`.

Comment: [62](https://tio.run/##LYrtCoMgGEb/exUvDMKkYtZIyNyNjA3CbAh9UQpadO2tYr/O4TmPHMf4K@V@071sba2g1MNsJlV1T1RZM0Aj9tcbn0pcdMGHq@4NLILggyR0n794Piljp57gph2qYwgWvvH9PHeV7nGIVgRwNXCC5gl7sDQCL2iaJTnlR5xNXRRysAbKEhocuCjwIUfbzhKaPe6pijP2Aw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Taking into consideration @Neil's suggestion it would get to 48 bytes: `#define f(x,y)({*(int*)x^=*(int*)y;*(float*)x;})`

Comment: Actually I've missed the obvious, so another -8 bytes: `#define f(x,y)({*(int*)x^=*(int*)y;*x;})`

Comment: [Saves 2 more](https://tio.run/##LYzdCoMgGEDve4oPglBxgW0UlO1RBuLPEEqjDJSxZ3du7O5wDhy5bZenlLm2Ti6n0sCtP8KuxXrPtdLGOg0GRZowIIKsCwTHx/ynRAkyixdfiXNRsArrEK5eFcAvQJxZ3w63oaOQZtZd255NJR5BjaP0ZwDOy7@JtEl4qt75Aw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##LczdCoMgGIDh867igyBUXGAbBaW7lIH4M4TSKANl7NqdBzt74IVX7fvtrVRpnVfrpQ1wF854GLk9S6uNdd6ARYlmjAhyPhKcXuKvTEnCpRI26TzCzacBsGuQEZJgYz89poFCFmy49yNbajyjnmcVrgic122XaJfx0nzLDw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online") after merging with @AZTECCO's solution.

Comment: Does this work on expressions like `f(3.0+1.2,0)`?

Comment: @PurpleP no because it takes pointers to floats as its arguments.

Comment: Note that this is only "safe" in debug mode, or if you use `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.  Maybe you should have specified C++ (MSVC) if you wanted to use type punning via pointer casting.  Although it does work on G++ with optimization disabled.  BTW, this also requires a C++ implementation where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, so it won't work on G++ for AVR or MSP430 for example.  (TIO runs on x86, which uses 32-bit int and float like all "normal" modern CPUs).

Comment: You don't need a comma or GNU C statement-expression here; the golf rules allow returning a value by modifying an input operand by reference.  Also, since this is golf, this version doesn't strictly need the `()` safety parens.  The "caller" just has to make sure not to use it as part of a larger expression.  It already has lots of other weirdness (like taking args by reference and destroying one of them).

Comment: I have a better solution (but it's C-only).

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I’ve modified my answer in accordance with this - thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## ARM Thumb Machine Code, <strike>6</strike> 4 Bytes

48 40 70 47

In assembly:

```
EORS R0, R1 ; Exclusive Or of the first two params, store result in the return register
BX LR       ; Branch to the value stored in the Link Register (Return address)
```

Under the standard Arm calling convention, the first two parameters are passed in the registers R0 and R1, results are returned in R0, and LR holds the return address. Assuming you're using the soft float ABI with 32 bit floats, this will perform the desired operation in 4 bytes.

-2 bytes thanks to Cody Gray

Comment: Would it be possible to use `EORS r0, r1` instead, in order to save 2 bytes? That's only a 2-byte instruction (`48 40`), compared to your 4-byte `EOR`. You're already targeting Thumb, so this should work fine, as far as I can see. The only difference is it updates status flags, but you don't care about that side effect in this case.

Comment: You should specify that this is using the soft-float ABI which passes FP args in integer registers, not VFP / NEON `s0` and `s1`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy, <s>75</s> 59 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:(x.view("i")^y.view("i")).view("f")
import numpy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9JKo0KvLDO1XEMpU0kzrhLB1oQy05Q0uTJzC/KLShTySnMLKv8XFGXmlWikaYB5emk5@YklxkYahmZ65ibmRpo6aMJGxnpmhpqamv8B)

Defines a lambda which takes two numpy float32 arrays as its arguments and returns a numpy float32 array.

Thanks to @ShadowRanger for saving 14 bytes, and Joel a further 2!

If the import can be dropped (since my lambda itself calls methods on numpy objects rather than any base numpy functions), I could save a further 13 bytes. I’m uncertain on this from the code golf standard rules.

Comment: It's shorter than Jelly and Ruby answers. Nice!

Comment: You can shave off 27 bytes (dropping it to 48 bytes) by removing the import entirely (just assume the caller passed you `numpy.float32`s so you can use their methods) and replacing both `int32` uses with `'i'` and the `float32` usage with `'f'`; the `dtype` parameter can be a string which gets converted to the real `dtype` for you, and conveniently, `'i'` and `'f'` are legal ways to make those dtypes, which removes the need for the function to import `numpy` stuff into its namespace at all. Not sure if it's Code Golf legal to remove the import but still assume `numpy` inputs...

Comment: [Example showing it works with the import itself being unavailable to `f`](https://tio.run/##RYzLCsIwEEX3/YrZZQZKoIm0UPBXhEg7ONA8CFGbr4@iRe/qcA7cVMstBtsanzfnr4uDva8z7voh6xOVKLrUP9OBrKgtK4N3EpDmDt7jHD2Eu08VxKeYC/AWXbHmU1OWUJDxcDiMejpNhvqfMFaPAxF139P2Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I thought the imports had to be included, but I’m not sure. Thanks for the tip re the dtypes!

Comment: @NickKennedy: Yeah, if the import is required, it only saves 8 bytes (two each from `int32` to `'i'`, four from `float32` to `'f'`), but that's still something. If the import is strictly required, you could just change it to `import numpy` to assert the package exists, without using `from numpy import*` to extract names from it. That would get you another six bytes, down to 61 bytes total.

Comment: The `f=` part can be omitted per [rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/88506). Also, the inputs do not have to be converted to arrays, they can just be `np.float32` numbers: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9JKo0KvLDO1XEMpU0kzrhLB1oQy05Q0uTJzC/KLShTySnMLKv8XFGXmlWikaYB5emk5@YklxkYahmZ65ibmRpo6aMJGxnpmhpqamv8B).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) + numpy, <s>89</s> 77 bytes

```
“(F(“I^F(“IvF).item()”;"F“¢lẒṾ:/²)Ɓɱ¡vẠ⁷5Rʠ¡7ɼṆṪ{ė4¶Gẉn`¡Ð}ṫȥṄo{b»Ḳ¤¹ṣḢ}jʋƒŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZoAZf9qZWxsef//4oCcKEYo4oCcSV5GKOKAnEl2RikuaXRlbSgp4oCdOyJG4oCcwqJs4bqS4bm@Oi/CsinGgcmxwqF24bqg4oG3NVLKoMKhN8m84bmG4bmqe8SXNMK2R@G6iW5gwqHDkH3huavIpeG5hG97YsK74biywqTCueG5o@G4on1qyovGksWSVv///zE2Ljc0NzIsMTIzLjYx)

Has the dubious honour of being longer than the Python 3 code it reproduces, largely because of the need to convert to/from numpy objecte and the fact that numpy isn’t loaded by Jelly so the `__import__()` built-in has to be used.

A monadic link taking the two floats as a list as its argument and returning a float.

Evaluates the following Python 3 code:

```
(__import__('numpy').float32(x).view("i")^__import__('numpy').float32(y).view("i")).view(__import__('numpy').float32).item()
```

where `x` and `y` are substituted with the input.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for 1-column matrix of two IEEE 754 64-bit floating-point numbers (binary64) from stdin. Prints one such number to stdout.

```apl
645⎕DR≠⌿11⎕DR⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@ZiemjvqkuQY86Fzzq2W9oCOH0TQXJ/lcAgwKuR72rDM30zE3MjRQMjYz1zAy5kGSM9IwUTPRMkIXM9SwsLRSM9UyAAAA)

`⎕` prompt (numbers that collapse to non-floats can be forced into floats with the function `⊃⊢⎕DR⍨645,⍨⎕DR`)

`11⎕DR` convert to 1-bit Binary (1) **D**ata **R**epresentation (2-row, 64-column matrix)

`≠⌿` vertical XOR reduction

`645⎕DR` convert to 64-bit float (5) **D**ata **R**epresentation (single number)

Answer (score 5):

## [VAX BASIC (later VMS BASIC, then Compaq Basic)](https://www.vmssoftware.com/pdfs/HP_branded_docs_1st_batch/5424pro.pdf), 11 bytes

```basic
H = F XOR G
```

Seems a bit silly to me, obviously, older languages will do better because they didn't worry abut strong-typing issues as much.

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! I've edited out what appears to be an extraneous header, but if not feel free to edit it back in, along with any accompanying information

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 59 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)(t=@typecast)(bitxor(t(a,u='int32'),t(b,u)),'single')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBCoAgEAXQ4zgfhlmYW6GraGgIoVFT1OktqN2D1yYNZ@rZi0gfKXAEqR/1XtMUdgXFolfbSN86vClVB2vASpEPgM1e6rwkg57pI1mx4N9OHNAf)

Typecast is the MATLAB/Octave way of casting without changing the underlying bits. This is required because `bitxor` only works on integers. No idea why they never implemented floating point numbers, even though you can explicitly specify the `AssumedType` as a third argument to `bitxor`. I guess the only use is recreational programming.

Comment: Bitwise stuff on FP bit patterns is useful in assembly language to do things with the sign bit, or rarely to stuff an integer into the exponent field as part of an `exp()` implementation.  But I assume Octave already has functions/operators for copysign and negation.  And they don't care about micro-optimizations like using AND (with a constant mask) then XOR to conditionally flip the sign of one value based on the sign of another.  In a real optimization project in asm (actually C with AVX intrinsics) I have used XOR of floats then looking at the sign bit to avoid cmp against zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>105</s>  101 bytes

*Shorter Node version suggested by @Neil*
*Saved 4 more bytes thanks to @ShieruAsakoto*

Takes input as `(x)(y)`.

```javascript
x=>y=>(v=Buffer(4),v.writeInt32LE((g=n=>v.writeFloatLE(n)&&v.readInt32LE())(x)^g(y)),v.readFloatLE())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxRC4IwFEbf@yFyL9QF51B7mA9BQdBvCIZuYowt5lr6621CPkTf4zmH7yGjHFs/PMPBuk4tWiyTaGbRQBSnl9bKA8d9pLcfgrraULDbGaAXVjRfeDFOhgQtZlkkr2S3ZYgw4b2HGdeH1Wwt4tI6OzqjyLgeNOQlVbxiCDkrqMwRd7@eUXKc@J@oqD7WCAXxtHT7AQ)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 115 bytes

Takes input as an array of 2 floats.

```javascript
a=>(v=new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4))).getFloat32(v.setUint32([x,y]=a.map(n=>v.getUint32(v.setFloat32(0,n))),x^y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBDoIwEEX3noJlm9SJQAO6KInGeAPdEEwm2BIMtgRqgdNjMboxzur/vPfnjg77sqtbu9bmJmclZhQZcULLITiixUstB7KUfdfhdHgqJTvCKaVQSXtqDNo4Ig56ac@1XnI@sqkQCA9siRaZW7wPemvfzYZp/4WN14nSuTS6N42ExlREkTxMIOVpxIIwiiEJC0pXP0YEnnLgf1AK292WBTFwf57PLw)

Comment: FYI Node's `Buffer` saves a few bytes: `a=>(v=new Buffer(4),[x,y]=a.map(n=>v.writeFloatLE(n)&&v.readInt32LE()),v.writeInt32LE(x^y),v.readFloatLE())`.

Comment: @Neil Thanks! (saved 2 more bytes by using a function instead of `map`)

Comment: Dropping the `new` in `new Buffer(4)` should also work iirc

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 92 bytes

```cs
x=>BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle(x.Aggregate(0,(a,b)=>a^BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctBC8IgGMbxe59EwSRst02homDnBh2iQOVVBFNQV4Pos9tgEHR64M/z03mts6unMeiuP4bxAUkqD53xURZBljG8TlzsXTnE8IRUINE@lC2bSx7i2QXrAU10Z20CKwugDUGSKMyFvP@p5TrEn0YKY1zb1SW5mRkU4HW9vRllhjS0MR@M2/oF)

Comment: You could [use unsafe code](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F@aV5yYlqrgVpqXbJOWk59YoqOATNkppNn@16jQqdS0tasuSyxSSLLV0sjMK9HSVKuIg7EqrYtSS0qL8rQ0wHqAIknWtf@tucKLMktSNdI0jPSM0nRM9EzSNDWtuf4DAA) for this, though I'm not sure if the "unsafe" keyword should affect the bytecount or not.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>31</s> 27 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Grimy*

```perl
$\=unpack f,$a^=pack f,$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxrY0ryAxOVshTUclMc4Wxoyvrf7/39BMz9zE3IjL0MhYz8zwX35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
4Z%Z}Z~9Z%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yRKNao2qs4ySvX//2gjPSMFEz2TWAA)

Splitting with `Z}` was shorter than taking two inputs `,4Z%]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>109</s> <s>76</s> 63 bytes

```java
a->b->a.intBitsToFloat(a.floatToIntBits(a)^a.floatToIntBits(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@xbsIwEJ3tr7jRlhqrRWyUDB2QOnSCDVHpEiBy6thWfEFEFd/u2iFdqOrh/O7dvbt3LV6waI9fUXfe9QRtytVA2qjzYGvSzqrNDFac@6EyuobaYAjwgdrCN2czGQgpfRenj9ClkthSr22zPwD2TZC5k52NQ4IrrGGTkfLYh9MERW7aPx/kisPDu4vGf0UvWcTYr83XqfT0mOZYls06YlFWRYlKW3rTFHZuHqWmPTv3fucFys8/XCVlZCxv246BTp1yQ/KTziRjRaPQezOKq5zBKLOxG7/FuFCLuFTLHw)

Been a while since I golfed in Java and I'm not certain if I need the declaration on the LHS as part of the byte count? If it used DoubleBinaryOperator the LHS would be shorter, but the RHS would have to use Double.doubleToLongBits and Double.longBitsToDouble, so that's actually longer.

Thanks to Neil for a substantial savings on the byte count!

Thanks to Unmitigated for currying the way to another improvement!

Comment: IIRC you don't even need the assignment as part of the byte count, only as part of any test suite you might include in your Try it online! header.

Comment: @Neil Thank you! That makes a big difference!

Comment: 63 bytes: `a->b->a.intBitsToFloat(a.floatToIntBits(a)^a.floatToIntBits(b))`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@xbsIwEJ3tr7jRlhqrRWyUDB2QOnSCDVHpEiBy6thWfEFEFd/u2iFdqOrh/O7dvbt3LV6waI9fUXfe9QRtytVA2qjzYGvSzqrNDFac@6EyuobaYAjwgdrCN2czGQgpfRenj9ClkthSr22zPwD2TZC5k52NQ4IrrGGTkfLYh9MERW7aPx/kisPDu4vGf0UvWcTYr83XqfT0mOZYls06YlFWRYlKW3rTFHZuHqWmPTv3fucFys8/XCVlZCxv246BTp1yQ/KTziRjRaPQezOKq5zBKLOxG7/FuFCLuFTLHw)

Comment: @Unmitigated Thank you! Excellent currying!

Answer (score 2):

## C, 23 bytes

```
f(int*x,int*y){*x^=*y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCoMgGIXvfYqfxkLDyayoi9aeZAxCkwmlo9lQomd3RTsXBz7OxxEXJ0SMCmvjMk/3DmTJ/LPNQrPGkzZimGUPt4@T2rLXHaHNgbHTBn@tlgQtCLaowXYOPLTAK1aXda4ohJ3yglVcNYeEU08hDeTA97RdKZycGS8L9TAJBf@fpt7Nk4Frg9b4Aw)

This might be a bit shifty; it takes the pointers to `float`s as pointers to `int`s.

However, it does work (this is C after all).

This takes advantage of acceptable input by taking a pointer to the variable and modifying it in-place. No (usable) value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

### [Wolfram Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com), 50 bytes

```
BitXor@@(FromDigits[RealDigits[#,2,32,0][[1]],2]&)
```

Although I strongly suspect that this could be more golfed, the two extra arguments in `RealDigits` function seem to be necessary for getting a correct result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8psyQiv8jBQcOtKD/XJTM9s6Q4Oig1MQfKVNYx0jE20jGIjY42jI3VMYpV0/yv71BtqAcU1jOtjf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>78</s> 67 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to @grawity.

```ruby
->x{[x.pack("gg").unpack("NN").inject(&:^)].pack(?N).unpack(?g)[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euojq6Qq8gMTlbQyk9XUlTrzQPwvHzA3Iy87JSk0s01KziNGMhiuz94Ers0zWjDWJr/xeUlhQrpOklJ@bkaEQbmumZm5gb6SgYGhnrmRnGanKhSBvpAaVM9EzQxc31LCwtdBSM9UyAIFbzPwA)

Input is an array of two floats.

Comment: `x.map{|v|[v].pack(?g).unpack(?N)[0]}` ⇒ `x.pack("gg").unpack("NN")`

Comment: @grawity: Awesome, thank you very much! The code is still longer than in Python, though. :-/

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 73 bytes

```lua
a,b=('II'):unpack(('ff'):pack(...))print((('f'):unpack(('I'):pack(a~b))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/USfJVkPd01Nd06o0ryAxOVtDQz0tDcgDs/X09DQ1C4oy80o0QOLIijxhahLrkjSB4P///4ZmeuYm5kb/DY2M9cwMAQ)

This code assumes 4-bytes unsigned integers and floats which is configuration on `tio.run`. Run as full program with input as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 8 bytes (2 instrs)

Really, just put in an xor command.

```
00000000: c600 0001 f801 0000                      İ¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

```
xorflt  XOR $0,$0,$1
        POP 1,0
```

Simples.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
~=reinterpret
!x=Float64~⊻((Int~x)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v862KDUzryS1qKAotYRLscLWLSc/scTMpO5R124NDc@8kroKTT09Pc3/DsUZ@eUKitFGekY6JnomsVxcacZGGhWaEA3GRnANQCZECxcXRA9IHVQRXLfmfwA)

expects `Float64`s on a 64 bit platform. On a 32 bit platform, use `Float32`

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 36 bytes

```
f::!Real!Real->Real
f _ _=code{xor%}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBNb4JAEIbv/IopTSOkgAUJWqOe6sGkh6b2BmgWWHCbZZfCakuMf710kLrJzrzPfsy8mZRTIrpSZkdOoSRMdPl8fvdOCb8Ge9VHLYc97JepzOj5R9YPl46VlawVbFW2Fifrg/4oGI9BCt5CTb@OrKYZ5LKGqqZKtZiYUEwUoA4UFG1Uo20VwQJL@JRMgB6JSOgQ3kAHThWkeJ0DgQTwNCSweAQddrhRJAMtB0phjuYryFhTcdLiYwsSC9I4higCoycTFvbQOta@mToMGguEhhs4U3/qWeB6EydwTQsMz0H0Hb/XU2f2PLNg4vi4zFi7Nanxc29TYC6Q0OT5nuUGa9YnKgwx9nZG4NuVaZqjp9HIHUVRtbBD13ECP75oxf@c7dVGKK24zVfIvawu3W@ac1I0nb157V5aQUqWIiRXfuNE4XDLPw)

Thankfully the `Real` and `Int` types are the same sizes on 64-bit platforms...
Unfortunately requires a complete signature otherwise the graph turns into a pretzel and everything segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 87 bytes

```javascript
x=>(v=Buffer(8),x.map((c,i)=>v.writeFloatLE(c,h=4*i)),v.map(e=>e^v[h++]).readFloatLE())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpBDoIwEIXhvSfpSJ2E0gAuysJEV96AYNLgVGqQkoKV21di4sb4lu//7jroqfV2nHeDu1I0Ki6qYkEdnsaQZyXwBR96ZKzlFlQV8OXtTKfe6fl8XM9Oya0F4OGjSFV0CXWXJA2gJ339QoDYumFyPWHvbsywOs2xkIXgqcgwTxuAzQ8QKLhE@acUWO5LnqFct@b4Bg)

silly

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 40 bytes

```
[ [ float>bits ] bi@ bitxor bits>float ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZCdWpSXmqNQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVlpGekYKJn8j9aIVohLSc/scQuKbOkWCFWISnTAYhLKvKLQFSxHVhSIfZ/cmJOjoLefwA)

```
                     ! 2.2 4.4
[ float>bits ] bi@   ! 1074580685 1082969293
bitxor               ! 8388608
bits>float           ! 1.175494350822288e-38
```